# Am I unsuccessful if I don't get promoted?

Tags: career-development

My coworker and I joined this company at the same time (about one month apart from each other). I struggled for the first few months and got “Meets Expectations” for my first review. Since then, I have received “Exceeded Expectations”. I had asked about a promotion about 2 years in, and was told that it was really difficult to get one. But I persevered anyway, became very well-known within the company, with great feedback and people telling me I should work on problems with bigger scope. Eventually got a promotion 3 years in.

Then I found out that my coworker had got his promotion 1 year in. This made me unhappy because I felt lied to - it’s not that it’s hard, but that you needed more impactful projects. If I had known that, I would have pushed for such projects. In retrospect, I should have pushed harder when they gave me a wishy-washy answer.

I brought initiatives to the table, but I can’t work on all of them so I had to give some of them away. I wish I could have done all of it because you only get credit for execution and not for coming up with ideas. If I had been able to do all of it (some are multi-quarter initiatives) then I think I would have had a stronger case for promotion. In fact, some of the tasks for these projects are now delegated to me by the peer that got promoted. This is making me feel inferior, because now the peer can claim he delegated tasks to me and is therefore at a higher level.

So my questions are:

- Is it fair to equate promotions to success? In my mind if I’m not getting promoted but my peers are, then I’m not successful (even though I’m getting good reviews)
- Along the same lines, is it wrong to say I’m not successful because I’m not getting promoted? Am I being too hard on myself?

Comment: Welcome to Workplace.SE. I think your question can be improved by clarifying what you want and focus on one main issue. Right now the question feels like it is all over the place and it is not clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: "When I found my feet, I really stuck the landing - started becoming the main stakeholder for a complex vertical" > Is something missing here? This part sounds awkward.

Comment: Thank you, let me rewrite this. Should I close it for now, and then reopen it when I have a better description?

Comment: Maybe start with clarifying what you want to achieve. In your title you ask about being successful without promotion, but your question sounds like you actually want to be promoted faster.

Comment: Thanks folks, I have re-written my question. Hopefully this one is clearer.

Comment: This sounds backwards to me. _Promotions don't make you successful, being successful gets you promotions!_

Comment: IME, being successful doesn’t always get you promotions in the sense that you can do your job really well and get good reviews but not perform at the next level. Which is why I am wondering if promotions make you successful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it fair to equate promotions to success? In my mind if I’m not
> getting promoted but my peers are, then I’m not successful (even
> though I’m getting good reviews)

We each have different definitions of success. I believe that if you are achieving your personal career goals, then you are successful.

For some, success occurs when they achieve a particular title like Vice President. For others, industry recognition equals success. And others measure their success by their monetary compensation. For many, it's a combination.

Consider your career goals, then see if you feel successful.

> Along the same lines, is it wrong to say I’m not successful because
> I’m not getting promoted? Am I being too hard on myself?

It seems like you did get promoted. And it seems like you were happy until you saw that a coworker got promoted faster than you did.

IMHO, that's a mistake. Measure yourself against your own goals, and not against the achievements of others.

If you got the same promotion after three years, but your coworker didn't get promoted at all, would you feel better (even though you would be in exactly the same position as you are now)? I don't think you should.

Comment: Thank you. You and Kilisi make some good points. I had stopped comparing myself to others because landing this job was a big life event for me. Now with the economic downturn I have started doubting things, leading to these kind of tendencies. I’ll step back and be objective about it. Doing my perf review today oddly made me feel better of myself and how far I’ve come. Thanks to the community!

Answer (score 4):

> Is it fair to equate promotions to success?

This is purely up to the individual. Many people would not want a promotion. Many others make more money than their managers.

So while some equate status in the company hierarchy with sucess, others idea of sucess is just paying their bills and giving their kids a good life, to others it's all about how much $$, or how much authority, or how long they can get away with it.

Comment: What about from a company perspective? If I don’t get promoted as fast as my peers, am I a detriment to the business? 

On a personal / career level it clearly is (to me, but that depends on the individual like you said).

Comment: There are often limits on how many promotions management may issue per year. Not being promoted, if it means anything, means that someone was judged more worthy, not that you were judged unworthy. Yes, it's annoying as heck.

Comment: It would be up to the perception of the individual at the company. As an entity a company needs experienced workers a lot more than management. So many people value them highly whether it's a cleaner or a senior tech. They're the bread and butter staff. Others are more impressed by status.

Answer (score 0):

It is always fair to ask you manager what the company needs to see from you to merit promotion, and how competitive the process is.

The first few promotions are often almost automatic. After that, like raises, you start running into someone's idea of what the company structure and budget will allow, and you start having to compete for recognition. This is where knowing more about the exact definition of the next role and the measurement criteria being used becomes important. Promotion is often recognition that you have already been working at the next level.

Also note that being promoted may actually lower your performance rating since you're now being evaluated against a higher standard. Don't be surprised if it drops you from Exceeds Requirements to Meets Requirements for a while. That isn't a failure, it just means you haven't completely mastered this step and started moving up to the next one yet.

At the higher level, you will also start running into the fact that some companies drew up their charts assuming that moving into management was a desirable promotion. Of course for some of us it isn't. My ex-employer did have technical ratings going all the way up, but even so they involved progressively more analysis and advising rather than hands-on work, and folks had to decide if that was a role they were comfortable moving into. Declining to move up is also not a failure, if the company still values your current contributions.

(Though if you "stay in band" too long you have to be content with watching the young hotshots pass you, and may face some ageism or belief that you could be replaced by someone with fewer years of raises. Companies rewarding long and dedicated service is, alas, a dying tradition.)